# ASP classic application hungs at function call

Tags: debugging, function, asp-classic

Good day!

I'm experiencing an issue with an ASP classic application we have. We were working on the SQL connection management and everything was perfect, so we deployed on another environment for the users to test and one of the ASP page hungs for 90 sec and results in:

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0113' 

Script timed out
```

So, I tried adding some debug code. What I used is:

```
Response.End
```

To check where it was hanging. I finally discovered that it was the new function we developed that was hanging, obviously! Here's a little extract:

```
Dim sqlConn
Set sqlConn = SessionConnection("SQLConnection")
set rsIDXMDL = SQLQuery(sqlConn, sQuery)
```

If I put a Response.End just before the call to SessionConnection(), the process stops. If I put the Response.End after the call to SessionConnection(), the page hangs for 90 sec. That made me think: "Bingo! Something inside fails!" So, just for fun, I put a Response.End at the first line of the function, like:

```
Function SessionConnection(SessVarName)
    Response.End
    [...]
```

I'm sure you can guess what happened!!! THE PAGE STILL HANGS!!! How is this possible?

Comment: Instead of `Response.End` use `Response.Write("I am at line this and that doing that and this")` followed by `Response.Flush` then you will hopefully get some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to improve the code's efficiency so that it does't time out at all however if that's somehow not possible as a band aid you can try to increase the timeout:

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 180
```

This value indicates how long, in seconds, the server will let an ASP script run until it is stopped by the server. The default value is 90 seconds.

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 120 
    conn.Open <connectionString>
```

Where conn is an ADODB.Connection object that is not yet open, the connectionTimeout property will indicate the amount of time, in seconds, to wait for an ASP application to initially connect to the data source. The default is 15 seconds

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    conn.Open <connectionString> 
    conn.CommandTimeout = 120
```

CommandTimeout tells the server how long to wait, in seconds, for completion of any command sent to the data source. This value is editable before and after the connection has been opened. The default is 30 seconds

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Problem is, the script fails between the call to the function SessionConnection and the first line of that function... Somewhere that is out of our code. Moreover, the same click on the same button in production (with the old session management) is processed in less than half a second.